# JSF 2.0 Jquery/JS retrieving a value of selectOneRadio in Javascript/jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am developing a JSF 2.0 application. How would one check which radio button was selected from my Java script/jquery code?

My radio button code is

```
   <t:selectOneRadio id="options" value="#{reqscope.selectedRadio}" layout="spread">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="policynum" itemLabel="Policy number" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="custId" itemLabel="Customer ID" />    
</t:selectOneRadio>


   <t:radio for="options" index="0"  name="search_by1" onclick="policyradioselected()" />
    <t:radio for="options" index="1"  name="search_by" onclick="customerradioselected()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input[name=options]:checked').val()
```

should work assuming generated html looks like this for inputs:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="options:0" value="Yourvalue1" />
```